# IOS Applicationdidenterbackground set root view controller nil

Tags: ios, memory, background, appdelegate

I'm developing an IOS application that uses background tracking.  In order to minimize my memory footprint in the background I'd like to get rid absolutely everything in my app that can be rebuilt (everything except the class containing the location manager).

In each of my viewcontrollers I have implemented the dealloc method with:

NSLog(@"Destroyed: %@", self);

Now, in the app delegate method "applicationdidenterbackground" I set:

[self.window setRootViewController:nil];

This should work fine as that is the only reference back to my view controllers, however, when I run the application and press the home button nothing happens.  It's not until I bring the application back to the foreground that I receive the messages that the views have been destroyed.  I have also verified it's not just a log delay, using instruments I can see the memory is still allocated until the application returns to the foreground.  Same thing with Applicationwillresignactive.

Is this behavior normal?  If so, what is the correct way to destroy unwanted objects when the application goes into the backgroun?  Thanks

Steve